# Helper in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, styles, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I'm using TextInputLayout to present a form.
I would like to present an helper for each input by using error line as I couldn't find an other way.

So I have created a style :

```
<style name="LayoutHelperStyle" parent="EditTextBaseStyle">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item> // blue
   <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item> // blue
</style>
```

Here is the call to set the helper :

```
private void setHelper(TextInputLayout layout, String hintText, int styleId) 
{
   layout.setErrorEnabled(true);
   layout.setError(hintText);
   layout.setErrorTextAppearance(styleId);
}
```

It's working fine except the underline remains red instead of using the colorControlActivated color.
What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: EditText has a dedicated method for that: setError(errorText)

Answer (score 0):

In support library 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' you can now set helper text to textInputLayout.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.html#setHelperText(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

With the Material Components Library you can use the **`helperText`** attribute:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:helperText="Helper Text"
```

[image]